# How many lattice paths from (-5,-3) to (7,4) pass through neither (-1,1) nor (3,2)?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am working through Carl Wagner's Basic Combinatorics (http://www.math.utk.edu/~wagner/papers/comb.pdf). On page 103 there is a problem about lattice paths I'm attempting solve.

It's unclear to me how I would solve for a problem that passes through (or does not pass through) multiple points. My intuition is to count from (-5,-3) to (-1,1) which gives 8 choose 4, then count from (-1,1) to (3,2) which gives 5 choose 1, then from (3,2) to (7,4) which gives 6 choose 2. Using the multiplication principle to multiply each binomial coefficient gives me the answer, correct?

To solve for passing through neither (-1,1) nor (3,2), I reason that I can take the total paths from (-5,-3) to (7,4), which gives 20 choose 13, & subtract out each of the above calculations for paths from (-5,-3) to (-1,1) which gives 8 choose 4, & from (-1,1) to (3,2) which gives 5 choose 1.

How can I generalize the correct methods for much larger distances so that I don't have to draw out the graph? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using inclusion-exclusion. Total path number minus going through $(-1,1)$ minus going through $(3,2)$ plus those going through both points.

Comment: This gives me the solution to passing through neither points, correct? Is my reasoning behind calculating through both points correct?

Comment: To pass through both points, calculate three numbers, one from $(-5,-3)$ to $(-1,1)$, next from $(-1,1)$ to $(3,2)$, the third from $(3,2)$ to $(7,4).$ Then multiply these three numbers, as it represents the sequence of three necessary choices to go from $(-5,-3)$ to $(7,4)$ while hitting the desired two points along the way. It looks like that's what you meant to do for this part of the problem.

Comment: @BigD4J Yes, I was finding the paths going through neither point.